# How does the Pseudo-Satellite Zephyr land?

Tags: landing, airbus

I don't see how the [Airbus Pseudo-Satellite Zephyr](https://www.airbus.com/defence/uav/zephyr.html) solar plane can **land** safely.

It this [video](https://youtu.be/cwfbEMe5a4I?t=13), it is "thrown" to take off, but no gear or something similar is visible. Will it just land on its belly?

This [video](https://youtu.be/lVDMDR5FhW0?t=71) shows, I think, landing footage, but only the runway is visible.

Comment: I'm guessing if it's light enough to be carried by (multiple) hand and launched, it can probably be recovered with some sort of elevated arrester or net without too much risk of damage.

Comment: @aerobot thanks for the guess, but I am not sure what are these, and from searching the internet, it's not clear.. In any case, I can imagine what you mean, but still, the question remains alive!

Comment: It could land on grass without significant damage.  In any case, it's designed to stay aloft for months or years.

Comment: In the video I posted it lands on the runway @JohnK. So what you are saying is that it lands on it's belly. That could serve as an answer..

Comment: I don't know for sure what the design parameters are so I can't say for sure so I can't post as an answer.

Comment: I don't see how it could belly land with the props where they are

Comment: @TomMcW you are right, I guess...

Comment: It flies so slowly that my guess is that they catch it, like the reverse of launching. It's hard to tell if that video shows it landing or launching.

Comment: That's why I said "I think" @TomMcW. Having humans catch it on approach seems a bit of a stretch, since if something goes a bit wrong and one of them gets injured, it might get a too big negative impact in the public face of Ζέφυρος.

Comment: @TomMcW Plenty of RC model aircraft belly land, with the props positioned in such a way that they might hit the ground during a belly landing. The weight of the craft is light enough not to cause damage and the forces usually just spin them out of the way. This thing is 25 to 33 meters, so maybe that doesn't apply here...

Comment: @gsamaras If you're wondering what I meant by elevated arrester or net, you can check out the ScanEagle's recovery system. It's not exactly what I had in mind, nor even the same class of UAV, but I suspect you can get very creative/flexible about how to recover such light/slow vehicles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some power googling...

https://www.airforce-technology.com/projects/zephyr/

> Launch and recovery The air vehicle is launched by hand. **Recovery is
>   by belly landing as the air vehicle has neither landing gear nor
>   landing parachutes**.

https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/defense/2016-07-11/solar-powered-pseudo-satellite-display-farnborough-2016

> It is hand-launched by a five-man ground crew, and **recovered by belly-landing**.

http://en.ruvsa.com/catalog/zephyr/

> Launch: hand launch Recovery: **autonomous belly landing**

It has two-bladed props, so they can be positioned to avoid a ground strike.

Comment: If you could see my deleted answer, you'd see that my assumption about a belly landing was correct, still providing sources for it was essential, thanks!

Comment: The trick was to google "zephyr belly landing". :)